# Python: Search and Replace but ignore commented lines

Tags: python

I actually want to do a search and replace but ignore all my commented lines, and I also just want to replace only the first found...

input-file.txt

```
#replace me
#replace me
replace me
replace me
```

...like with:

```
text = text.replace("replace me", "replaced!", 1) # with max. 1 rep.
```

But I'm not sure how to approach(ignore) those comments. So that I get:

```
#replace me
#replace me
replaced!
replace me
```

Comment: This is not easy to do. You'll need to have a cache of all "first-seen" instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, the **existing solutions have one or more of several problems**:

- Incomplete (e.g. requiring match on start of line)
- Incomplete (e.g. requiring match not containing `\n`)
- Clunky (e.g. looong file-based solutions)

I'm pretty sure a pure-regex solution would require variable-width lookbehinds, which the `re` module doesn't support (though I think the `regex` module does). With a small tweak though, regex can still provide a fairly clean answer.

```
import re

i = re.search(r'^([^#\n]?)+replace me', string_to_replace, re.M).start()

replaced_string = ''.join([
    string_to_replace[:i],
    re.sub(r'replace me', 'replaced!', string_to_replace[i:], 1, re.M),
])
```

The idea is that you find the first uncommented line containing the start of your match, and then you replace the first instance of `'replace me'` that you find *starting on that line*. The `^([^#\n]?)+` bit in the regex says

1. `^` -- Find the start of a line.
2. `([^#\n]?)+` -- Find as few `([^#\n]?)` as you can before matching the rest of the expression.

   - `([^#\n]?)` -- Find 0 or 1 of `[^#\n]`.

     - `[^#\n]` -- Find anything that's not `#` or `\n`.

**Note** that we're using raw strings `r''` to prevent double escaping things like backslashes when creating our regex expressions, and we're using `re.M` to search across line breaks.

**Note** that the behavior is a bit weird if the string you're string to replace contains the pattern `\n#`. In that case, you'll wind up replacing part or all of one or more commented lines, which may not be what you want. Considering the problems with the alternatives, I'd be inclined to say the alternatives are all wrong approaches.

If that's not what you want, excluding all commented lines gets doubly weird because of some uncertainty in how they'd get merged back together. For example, consider the following input file.

```
#comment 1
replace
#comment 2
me
replace
me
```

What happens if you want to replace the string `replace\nme`? Do you exclude the first match because `\n#comment 2` is stuck in between? If you use the first match, where does `\n#comment 2` go? Does it go before or after the replacement? Is the replacement multiple lines as well so that it can still get sandwiched in? Do you just delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag that marks whether you have completed the replacement yet. And then only replace when that flag is true and the lines is not a comment:

```
not_yet_replaced = True
with open('input-file.txt') as f:
   for l in f:
      if not_yet_replaced and not l.startswith('#') and 'replace me' in l:
          l = l.replace('replace me', 'replaced!')
          not_yet_replaced = False
      print(l)
```

Comment: Couldn't you get rid of the flag and just break the loop. Also, in your current state, you still iterate over each line even though you know nothing will be replaced - as the flag is false

Comment: @NChauhan No to both since we must print each line (or the OP can modify to writing to an output file) no matter whether it is a comment, replaced line, or ignored line :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether or not you have managed to get the text out of the file, so you can do that by doing

```
f = open("input-file.txt", "r")
text = f.read()
f.close()
```

Then the way I would do this is first split the text into lines like so

```
lines = text.split("\n")
```

then do the replacement on each line, checking it does not start with a "#"

```
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if len(line) > 0 and line[0] != "#" and "replace me" in line:
        lines[index] = line.replace("replace me", "replaced!")
        break
```

then stitch the lines back together.

```
new_text = "\n".join(lines)
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `break` after the first occurrence like so:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read().split('\n')
    for i in range(len(content)):
        if content[i] == 'replace me':
            content[i] = 'replaced'
            break

with open('input.txt', 'w') as f:
    content = ('\n').join(content)
    f.write(content)
```

Output :

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ cat input.txt 
> #replace me
> #replace me
> replaced
> replace me
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If the input file is not very big, you can read it into memory as a list of lines. Then iterate over the lines and replace the first matching one. Then write the lines back to the file:

```
with open('input-file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    substr = 'replace me'    

    for i in range(len(lines)):
       if lines[i].startswith('#'):
           continue
       if substr in lines[i]:
           lines[i] = lines[i].replace(substr, 'replaced!', 1)
           break
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: This does require his matching string to not span multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a multiline regex along with its sub() method and giving it a count of 1:

```
import re
r = re.compile("^replace me$", re.M)
s = """
#replace me
#replace me
replace me
replace me
"""
r.sub("replaced!", s, 1)
```

Gives

```
#replace me
#replace me
replaced!
replace me
```

Online demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/StudiousIdealisticAbstracttype)